# how to login to majestic.com using c# for scraping data from other majestic page

Tags: c#, web-scraping, webrequest

i am trying to login at majestic.com using c# but its not working well its gives the error http 403 . when i try to access secure (authorize page).here is my code 
Any help will be much Appreciated.here is my code

```
string formUrl = "https://majestic.com/account/login";
string formParams = string.Format("EmailAddress={0}&Password={1}", "email@gmail.com", "123456");
string cookieHeader;
 WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
 req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 req.Method = "POST";
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams); req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
 using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream()) { os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 }
 WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
 cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
 string pageSource;
 string getUrl = "https://majestic.com/reports/site-explorer?q=daraz.pk&oq=sabzi.pk&IndexDataSource=F";
 // here its give the error
 WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl); getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
 WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse(); 
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Telerik Fiddler (its free) to analyse the exact HTTP traffic between your browser and the website. Use the website from your browser, and record the traffic, then compare the traffic generated when you use your code. This will clearly show you what you need to send in order to get passed the 403 Forbidden message.